# Make threads specific to a message channel in spring cloud GCP pubsub

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub, java-threads

I have a spring cloud application running GCP PubSub messaging. I've got 2 message inbound channels that is subscribed to 2 different subscribers. The problem I face during load/stress test of the application is that, with a specific no.of threads set as below :

```
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.executor-threads: 350
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.parallel-pull-count: 2
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.max-acknowledgement-threads: 700
```

when the processes pulled by messages of channel 1 are busy, I don't have sufficient threads for channel 2 to pull messages. The solution would be is to restrict/configure no.of threads for each channel. I am finding a very hard time to figure this out. Please do help me out here ! Below are the channels I was referring to :

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel1")
public MessageHandler extractionMessageReceiver() {
    return message -> {
        // do something
    };
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel2")
public MessageHandler extractionMessageReceiver() {
    return message -> {
        // do something
    };
}
```

Note, the subscriber thread remains busy until the end of a particular process pulled by a message.

Comment: I'm familiar with Cloud PubSub, but not Spring. It seems like the question is mostly about Spring Service Activator throttling. Perhaps change the question to "How do I throttle ServiceActivator activations by inputChannel?"

Answer (score 0):

I had the following problem: when there were a lot of messages and they queued up, the actuator health check for pubsub stopped working. My assumption was that all the executor threads were busy handling the messages and the check run into a deadline exceeded exception.
The following flow control properties helped me to fix the issue:

| Config | Description |
| --- | --- |
| spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.[subscriber,publisher.batching].flow-control.max-outstanding-element-count | Maximum number of outstanding elements to keep in memory before enforcing flow control |
| spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.[subscriber,publisher.batching].flow-control.max-outstanding-request-bytes | Maximum number of outstanding bytes to keep in memory before enforcing flow control. |

From https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/_spring_cloud_gcp_for_pub_sub.html

When I set the max outstanding element count to 100 everything worked fine.

I think the outstanding messages get pulled with a stream. And with the properties above we can control that not all messages get processed at once. Instead, we split them up into, for example, 100 messages each. Maybe it will also switch between the channels. Quote from https://medium.com/google-cloud/things-i-wish-i-knew-about-google-cloud-pub-sub-part-2-b037f1f08318:

> Note, streaming pull only guarantees flow control on a best-effort basis. Say you’ve noted your application can only handle 100 messages in any one period, so you set max outstanding messages to 100. The client will pause once it has pulled in 100 messages, which works most of the time. However, if you then publish 500 messages in a single publish batch, the client will receive all 500 messages at once but only be able to process 100 at a time, potentially leading to a growing backlog of expired messages. This is because streaming pull can’t split up messages from a single publish batch. To avoid this, either increase your number of subscribers or decrease your batch sizes to match subscriber message processing capacity while publishing.

Could these parameters maybe solve your problem?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30087010)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).